# BQ24450 Texas Instruments

Tags: batteries, bjt, charger, texas-instruments, lead-acid

I need your help to find out why my lead acid battery is not fully charged when I am using the [BQ24450](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24450.pdf) by Texas Instruments.

[image]

These are my calculated values based on the fomula:

- Rt=150 ohm
- Ra=214.79k ohm
- Rb=17.21k
- Rd=594.4k ohm
- Rc=46k4 ohm
- Risns= 0.68 ohm
- Ccomp=10nF.

I connect DRVE to the collector of the external PNP (MJD32CT4) transistor I am using. I connect a resistor between DRVC and BASE of the transistor value (196 ohm.)

I am using 15V and a current limit of .65A from my external power supply.
This is the [datasheet of the battery I am trying to charge.](https://docs.rs-online.com/1856/0900766b81580e58.pdf)

I would like to know if my values and set up are correct and why my battery is not charging fully.

Comment: It's not that easy to spot the problem. How can you say that the battery is not fully charged?

Comment: I uses Stat1 and Stat2 to monitor each charging state. So i connect Stat1 to a buffer input  with the output connecting to an LED to indicate what state my battery is on. But state1 and Stat2 LED never comes On. I used an 100Ohm resistor to limit the current going through the resistor. The is power with a 5V from an external power supply

Comment: What is the actual output voltage when charging a battery? What conditions do you think **should** indicate "fully charged" and cause Stat1 to be asserted? Don't force us to reverse engineer your entire design.

Comment: I am using an electronics load and a PSU to replace the battery at the output but even if i vary the electronics to constant current and PSU to constant voltage. I can only see 10.8V reading at my electronics load.